# Serializing/Deserializing Dictionary<string,string> to XML

Tags: c#

I'm serializing a dictionary to an XML file with the following code:

```
[XmlArray]
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName="Element")]
public List<ElementClass> ParameterList
{
    get
    {
        return Parameters.Select(p => new ElementClass() { Key = p.Key, Value = p.Value }).ToList();
    }
    set
    {
        Parameters = value.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
```

This works fine, the XML that is produced looks fine, however when I deserialize the XML the Dictionary is always empty. I tried debugging the code, but for some reason only the Getter is called with the deserilazation. I can't seem to get my head around it where this is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the XmlSerializer tries to populate the `ParameterList` property, it first checks if it already has a value. If it does, it just adds items to it, and never sets the property. In other words, it does this:

```
var list = obj.ParameterList;
list.Add(deserializedElementClass1);
list.Add(deserializedElementClass2);
...
```

Not this:

```
var list = new List<ElementClass>();
list.Add(deserializedElementClass1);
list.Add(deserializedElementClass2);
...
obj.ParameterList = list;
```

Since the setter of your `ParameterList` property is never called during deserialization, the `Parameters` property is never assigned either.

Check out this XML-serializable dictionary implementation on Paul Welter's blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/444961

Comment: Thanks, that is strange though because I do initialize the list in my constructor to make sure it is there. The setter is only called for initialization when I assign the empty list. I still find it odd that the deserializer is not taking a "standard" xml array of a custom class.

Comment: @Martin, it is taking a standard XML array of a custom class, but it's just not doing things in the order you expect. It processes the items, rather than the array itself.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand :) or not, regardless I took your sample and made a copy to have it handle a string dictionary that serializes using attributes saving a few bytes here and there. Thanks!